# $(A+, \cdot)$ finite ring. If $(ab-1)b = 0$, then $b(ab-1) = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $(A,+,\cdot)$ be a finite ring, and $a,b \in A$ such that $(ab-1)b = 0$. Prove that $b(ab-1) = 0$.

I already have one solution for this problem and it involves using the fact that if $(A,+,\cdot)$ is finite, then $\exists k,m \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $b^k = b^m$ (we need to show that $bab = b$, so if $b = b^m$, $bab = bab^m = bab^2b^{m-2} = bbb^{m-2} = b^m = b$, because the hypothesis means that $ab^2 = b$; the solution involves using the hypothesis in proving that $\exists m\in \mathbb{N}, m>1$ such that $b = b^m$).

I am looking for a different solution, because this one seems rather "forced". I have solved other problems like this (for instance: $(M, \cdot)$ a finite monoid, then if $ab=1 \implies ba=1$) by assuming that the conclusion is false, then defining a function on $A$ (in the monoid example, $f:M \to M, f(x) = xa$ ) that is injective or surjective, and because $A$ is a finite set, then it is bijective, and thus I achieve a contradiction.

This kind of solutions seem more natural, at least for me, because in cases like this, when I have a relation between two elements in a ring, I try and "play" with them and achieve other relations involving them that will be useful in proving the problem.

I've tried constructing such a function for this problem, but I didn't succeed. It's harder on this particular problem because I can't prove that functions such as $f(x) = x(ax-1), f(x) = bx, f(x) = bxb$ (or others that are involving the hypothesis, but are using only the second operation of the ring) are injective or surjective, because multiplying by $b$ or $a$ and using the hypothesis, I get that $0=0$, which doesn't prove anything.

Can this problem be solved using this idea, or any other idea, without using the fact that in a finite ring every element $x \in A$ has two powers, $c,d \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $x^c = x^d$ ?

Any help (tips, solution) is appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1172540/ .

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution that I expected. Thank you very much, @darijgrinberg!

Comment: @C_M - In your original solution, you're saying you used $ab^2 = b$ in addition to $b^k = b^\ell$ to conclude $b=b^m$ for some $m>1$ right?

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Yes. Let $k,m \in \mathbb{N}^*, k<m$ such that $b^k = b^m$, where $k$ is minimal. Assume that $k > 1$. If $k=2$, then $b^2 = b^m \implies ab^2 = ab^m \implies b = ab^{2}b^{m-2} \implies b = b^{m-1}$, which contradicts the minimality of $k$. If $k>2$, then $b^{k-1} = b^{m-1}$ (using the same algorithm), which also contradicts the minimality of $k$. So $k = 1$ and $b = b^m$.